# Uncaught TypeError: format.writeGeometry is not a function at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

I would like to create a GML using openlayers to send to Geoserver to insert a new feature. While displaying writeGeometry() in console it displays the error like: Uncaught TypeError: format.writeGeometry is not a function

```
`var gml3 = format.writeGeometry(coords, {})`
```

*What's wrong with this code?*

Comment: None of the GML formats have a writeGeometry method.  You can only write features, or in some cases, geometry noes https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GML2-GML2.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GML3-GML3.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GML32-GML32.html